# Existence of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I would like to get a help about the next problem from my textbook:

**Problem:**

For which values of an $a \in \Bbb{R}$ the sum of a geometric series $2a + \sqrt{2a}+ a + \cdots$ equals 8? (first i wrote $\sqrt{2}a$, but it is $\sqrt{2a}$)

**My solution:**

First of all, i don't think that $2a$, $\sqrt{2a}$ and $a$, represent first three memebers of some geometric sequence. I think that this is a typo, and that it should be $a + \sqrt2a + 2a + \cdots$.

In this case we have a sequence of next numbers: $a, a\sqrt{2}, a(\sqrt{2})^2, a(\sqrt{2})^3, \ldots$ Here we have that common ratio is $q = \sqrt{2}$. From here we have that 
$$S_n = a \frac{1 - (\sqrt{2})^n}{1 - \sqrt{2}},$$
which gives us 
$$\lim_{n \to 0}S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a \frac{1 - (\sqrt{2})^n}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{a}{-(\sqrt{2} - 1)} \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - (\sqrt{2})^n) =     +\infty.$$
So, we have that this series converges to $+\infty$ and there isn't a $a \in \Bbb{R}$ for which the sum of given series is equal to 8 (the partial sums aren't the part of an answer).

Please, could you tell me if i made a mistake somewhere or the problem is in the typo and something else should be written?

Comment: Double ckeck, I guess the 2nd term must be $\sqrt{2}\cdot a$ hence it is a decreasing GP

Comment: Seems more likely to me that the first three terms should be $2a,\sqrt 2a,a\dots$. Note that $\sqrt2a\ne\sqrt{2a}$; possibly you simply misread it...

Comment: There *is* a typo. Either the second term is $\sqrt{2}a$ (the quotient is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) or the third term is $1$ (the quotient is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}$. I guess the first one is more likely to be the case, because for the second one you would need $a$ to be nonzero.

Comment: (Cont'd) So, try to solve the problem for $2a+\sqrt{2}a+a+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{a}{2}+\cdots$, which *is* a geometric series, and let us know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo. It should be $\sqrt{2}a$ instead of $\sqrt{2a}$. Now i got that $a = 4 - 2\sqrt{2}$. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be $$2a+\sqrt2a+a+...=8.$$

$$q=\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{2a}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=8.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes, now it works. In this case $a = 4 - 2\sqrt{2}$. Thank you for your time and help!